# No route matches but i use resources in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

in routes.rb i have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'account_activation/edit'

  root                     'static_pages#home'
  get       'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get       'sign_up' => 'user#new'
  get       'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post      'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete    'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  post      'sign_up',  to: 'user#create'
  resources :user
  resources :account_activation, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :purchases, only: [:create, :destroy]
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

i define in user_controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]


  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @purchases = @user.purchases.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @purchase = current_user.purchases.build
  end

  def index
    if logged_in?
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to sign_up_path
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_account_activation_email
      flash[:info] = 'check'
      redirect_to root_url(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def chart
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'updated'
      redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

both of them have a view but when i type localhost:300/user/(ID)/chart in browser rails tells me no route matches found but user/(ID)/edit works

when i use rake routes 
chart do not shows in routes

i see MHartl rubyonrails tutorial screen cast
he do everything like this
where is the problem?!

Comment: i defined chart in controller after edit befor update

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/user/6/chart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :user do
  member do
    get :chart
  end
end
```

define chart action like that
read `routes` in rails guide and check `member` and `collection`

`resources :user` creates only 7 default routes check 2.2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html